# How do you test only one file with Heft

Tags: node.js, npm, rush

I'm working on a project that recently implemented Rush. We're using [Heft](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rushstack/heft) as a test runner, so the main test command is `heft test`.

The problem is, no one knows how to only test one file. I tried using it with the `--locale` flag as well as with the `-t REGEXP` flag, but to no avail.

Any idea what the secret sauce is?

e.g.

```
src/apps/dashboard/components/Button/Button.test.tsx

# Jest syntax for testing one file / regexp except for heft

heft test -- button
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of Heft you are using, but I do not have Heft installed globally, so I use `npx` to use the version I have locally.

This works for me with heft `0.47.9`:

```
npx heft test --test-path-pattern src/path/to/my-test.test.ts
```